What conditions would allow this trojan horse be implemented on a universal scale?
A while ago, I posited this question "How to counteract a trojan horse when the horse is the anti-virus software?"
It seems that real life has presented an answer.

Major economic impact from outage unlikely, economic research business
says From CNN's Rob North and Olesya Dmitracova Capital Economics, an
economic research business, has provided an early assessment of the
wider consequences of the disruption.
“While things are still very uncertain, we do not anticipate a major
macroeconomic or financial market impact at this stage,” Jennifer
McKeown, chief global economist at the consultancy, wrote in a note.
“Those sectors operating with strong IT support systems will be
best-placed to experience only minor, short-lived effects. This might
explain why there has been little impact on financial markets so far…
Another reason for the muted impact in markets is that the founder and
chief executive of CrowdStrike itself has ruled out the possibility
that this relates to a cyber attack. Accordingly, the risk of
prolonged disruption is lower,” she wrote.\

This real-life event was caused by just such a scenario as I posited - an anti-virus program by a major well-respected company distributes a universally downloaded virus signature package that inadvertently targets a major kernel event in the Microsoft Operating System that prevents a modern computer from even booting. The results were almost instantaneous around the world. As soon as the update was automatically downloaded the computers crashed, giving the IT departments absolutely no warning and no ability to recover from except manual intervention.
It turns out that the potential devastation such an event could cause was mitigated by diversification. Only one of several Operating Systems was affected, the software was mounted only on select computer networks, it was mostly business software that was affected, and modern computers are not yet at the level of sophistication such that they can not be alternatively booted.

Global tech outage recovery could be a long process, with some devices
requiring manual rebooting From CNN's Brian Fung
The company behind a massive
computer outage across the world says a flawed update has been rolled
back — but that doesn’t necessarily help the thousands of businesses
that have been affected by the glitch.
Here’s why: The CrowdStrike software issue at the heart of the outage
runs at such a deep level in affected computers and systems that
getting them up and running just to be fixed will be, in many cases,
an enormous challenge.
That’s compounded by the fact that many of the servers that may
contain information needed to get these systems working again are
themselves caught in a cycle of crashing and rebooting.
The CrowdStrike software at fault operates at what’s called the kernel
level of a computer, a much deeper level than what more ordinary
applications such as browsers or video games do. This portion of a
device has much greater visibility and control over a computer and its
components, making it critical for the operation of all other systems
— and far more sensitive.
Running at the kernel level means CrowdStrike’s software can do more
to detect cyberattacks, but it also means the current bug is causing
Windows computers to crash to a “Blue Screen of Death” before users
can take any actions to correct it.
Manual rebooting: The issue appears to be recoverable, CrowdStrike has
said, but in many cases it requires painstaking work. Each affected
device must be accessed by an administrator and manually rebooted into
safe mode. Then, the offending CrowdStrike file must be deleted by
hand.
For businesses with hundreds or thousands of laptops, desktops and
servers running CrowdStrike’s security software, an individual human
may have to perform that process over and over and over again.
And organizations that take security seriously will have likely
encrypted their computers’ hard drives, making it even more
challenging to access the file that needs to be deleted.

In my scenario from my original question, this outage was caused, not by accidental blundering, but by malicious intent. As is often the case however, real life sometimes ends up being far scarier than fiction and not always a result of 'enemy action'.
As an adjunct to my original question, I pose the follow-up question: "what are the plausible conditions/scenarios whereby this disaster could be universally implemented, and affect all networked computers?"
EDIT
What I am after, is the method to create a completely homogenous system in the first place, such that every computer contains the same vulnerability. A system where there is no diversity, which is what saved us in this accident. What plausible scenario in some future society could account for a complete lack of diversification in the computer infrastructure of that society?

In Something Like Real Life: Not Many/None
As evidenced by the prevalence of IoT exploits, there is lots (and lots and lots) of network-accessible hardware which has no means of updating itself.
So even if you gain control of all update services for all operating systems (which itself is unlikely to the point of implausibility), millions of network-connected devices will continue to operate virus-free, having no agency by which to receive updates.
Moreover, as any porting company can tell you, writing something that works the same way on different substrates is hard.  You'd effectively have to rewrite your malicious software for every architecture connected to the global network.
But...
What if we imagine a world with an enforced monoculture?
Something like the setting of Paranoia, but with more computers than just the one.  A dictatorial system where if something tries to register for the equivalent of an IP address and has a hardware/software signature other than the government-approved one, jack-booted thugs literally kick down your door and demand your server hardware.
In that case, compromising the update mechanism is effectively total penetration of the entire global network.  But the fact that that is the case is largely the reason why heterogeneous networks are encouraged, and why mission-critical computers in military and bank backbone networks do not accept automatic updates.  So in your world, the ruling party would have to a) rule over IT with an iron fist, and b) be very, very dumb about their policies in so doing.

In my original question, it made clear that I am not asking about 'real life' earthly setting, I am talking about a very constructed society. In your scenario, there would be no need for a trojan horse, everything is universally tightly controlled anyway.

@JustinThymetheSecond Depends on what you want the Trojan Horse for.  If you want it to be a weapon for some One World Order/big brother initiative, then no, you don't need it, but I'd imagine if some evil conspirators wanted to hurt thier friend the computer, that it's universality would be its biggest weakness

What I am saying is that if there is an enforced monoculture in the entire world, then the possibility of 'enemy action' is not really indicated. However, in the scenario that actually happened, it was not 'enemy action' but 'unintended consequences', and in this scenario your solution is very valid.

Socialism (taken to the extreme).
The state owns the means of production.
That and a closed culture that doesn't trade with outside civilizations - leaving the only technology being that which the state sanctions to be made.
Sure they can send spies to pinch ideas from abroad, study what they find, innovate where they can (within sharp limits). Much of the state's energy will go to creating a myth of sanctity of the culture, avoidance of contamination by the outside. New ideas would be treated with profound mistrust and prejudice. The state government would be fearful and capricious in it's enforcement of behavioural norms.
How a country gets this way in a nutshell:
Any country would be vulnerable to a takeover after a war or crisis which unifies the people in a common purpose (eg. pandemic, energy-dearth, invasion attempt, food deprivation), a social revolution allowing supreme and unquestioned state-control for the benefit of all would be heralded by all political parties through a politburo. A military or propagandistic attack would be warded off, using the necessary techniques to do that to implement total informational control for the safety of all.
What it's like:
An highly ritualistic society: The old ways (as the head of state defines them) would predominate, change would be glacially slow, the people would live in a state of bliss (as proscribed by the Chairman/President/King/Emperor/Chancellor), their sole pursuit seeking an internal spiritual perfection through their work and the teachings of some or other holy-book (The Chairman Speaks... etc..). Everyone needs their daily spiritual guidance to function.
The tech:
The infrastructure, once it's attained a singular efficiency in doing not much more than basic file transfer and broadcasting the Chairman's thoughts and daily prayers - wouldn't need to change. One other thing it's used for......
What's the motive:
Say, you're a dictator, you're paranoid and fearful of loss of control. This state would also be fearful of change and signs of rebellion - these things would express themselves through any deviation from the sanctioned norms - thus the necessity for total surveillance and absolute control of the daily lives of the people. (What terrified and paranoid dictator would be without it?)
What's done:
The technology would be the tool of enslavement of the higher-functions, what's left of free-will after all the propaganda. This would necessitate remote root-access to each and every device in the realm by the Ministry of State Welfare or equivalent. No part of the infrastructure would escape the state's notice, through; transport, power-generation, resource-gathering, distribution and transport, all media and communications, the music (austere and slow rhythms, no-one should get too excited), perhaps to even include the timepieces - watches and clocks. Anyone showing resistance to the conditioning would be isolated and eliminated. The "contamination instance" would be safely removed causing a moment's standardized celebration of the the wisdom and beneficence of the Chairman.
The vulnerability:
Thus, everything would be vulnerable to using the god-like code-set that the state uses daily to deploy correct ideas and trim the errant behaviours of it's ant-like populace.
I can't see the state servers being easily hacked from outside, as they be designed to present no face outside the realm, but they do present a single point of failure for the right team to crack the country wide apart. Take the Ministry of Faith's servers, freeze-out the government, arrange a neck-tie party for the ophidians.
Aftermath:
The people, confronted by the silence from their tin-god's mouthpieces would be lost, not accustomed to the freedom of not being told what to do, not even knowing when to get-up or eat. Eventually, thirst and hunger would return the wild urges and bring a time of chaos. Ripe for takeover by a new beneficent force, or just letting them devolve to chaos and barbarism, a new Wild-West or Mad-Max post-industrial wilderness.

Global DNS servers are HIGHLY redundant.  If you hack a domain seller like GoDaddy, then yes, you can scramble all the domains that belong to GoDaddy and push them to all DNS servers, but if you hack a Global DNS server you can only mess up one of many copies of the Global DNS. It does not mean that you have what you need to authenticate as any Domain Seller you want to the other servers to update thier  records too.

I am not after an alternative method of achieving total computational shutdown, as in fact there are many alternatives for doing so. That is a different question. I am after a method that allows the proscribed method to happen.

Ah,, now I get what you're after. Editing. @JustinThymetheSecond

Yeah, I've changed the whole thing. @Nosajimiki

Yes, that is on the right track. It is a valid option.

Much better answer, reminds me of this question on Sec.SE. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/209908/does-lawful-interception-of-4g-the-proposed-5g-provide-a-back-door-for-hackers/209963#209963

In a constructed, controlled society, the answer is simple: design a vulnerability into the networking protocols.
Imagining this loosely in terms of TCP/IP, that could be something like allowing a ping to be broadcast to the entire network address space, which requires each machine to reply, with the same command, to the entire address space. At this point, the network becomes unusable because it's completely flooded with these pings. Disconnecting a machine lets it operate, but as soon as it is reconnected it falls victim to the attack.
You can't use the network to distribute a fix: it has to be done by physical means. Disconnecting every single machine, rebooting them and reconnecting them will work, if you can get every single machine disconnected. In a network of millions of machines that's hard to organise. Also, when most of the network is disconnected, the remaining machines will become usable, creating an incentive to keep them online.
Real TCP/IP implementations won't do this, of course. I based this idea on a tale from the mid-1990s of a "killer ping." That was a ping broadcast to an entire class A network, with up to 16 million machines, with a forged from-address, the address of the intended victim. The idea was that all the machines in the class A would reply to the victim, flooding it with traffic. Broadcast pings were taken out of use, as far as I know.
To have a vulnerability like this without it being designed deliberately, the simplest route is to have very strong intellectual property law. A single company managed to patent the basic idea of a computer network, and maintain and enforce a monopoly on the idea. It thus dominated its home market, and managed - probably via political influence over the government of its home country - to maintain a worldwide monopoly. So every computer runs the same implementations of the same protocols and has the same vulnerabilities.
I've based this on the Wright Brothers' attempts to patent the idea of a controllable aeroplane. The American courts accepted this and granted them a monopoly, which stifled development of aircraft in the US. The European courts would have none of this. They enforced Wright Brothers' patents on their specific control methods, but did not allow then to suppress development of other methods. When the US joined WWI, their domestic military aircraft were utterly obsolete, and they had to buy or build European aircraft to be able to run a useful air force.

TCP/IP is universally compatible, but not universally identical.  How it works internally on one device may be slightly different than another; so, even a vulnerability in TCP/IP is not guaranteed to exist on all platforms, and certain not to exist on all platforms by the time it reaches its current level of maturity. There have simply been too many hackers working on it for too long for a major, universal vulnerability to still exist.

@Nosajimiki: Yes, but the OP is asking for something for his centralised fictional world. I explained the concept in terms of TCP/IP because that makes the explaining easy. I said that real implementations won't do this.

What I am after, is the method to create a completely homogenous system in the first place, such that every computer contains the same vulnerability. A system where there is no diversity, which is what saved us in this accident.

@JustinThymetheSecond: See amended answer.

Yes, a strong Patent Law, winner-take-all. Microsoft and Bill Gates actually tried this, but they had to back off when Apple was almost bankrupt and the American government threatened Microsoft with an order to break up if Apple went under. In University we used to joke that IBM had a 'patent warehouse', and whenever a competitor rose up with a 'new idea'. IBM would pull out some patent or other from their warehouse and block them.

@JustinThymetheSecond in that case, you should consider looking at communist software practices where the government commissions software with built in government controls and requires all companies use it, because it's illegal to use anything else.

@Nosajimiki You and your anti-communist crusade. The only country that comes even close to this communist 'ideal' is Cuba,  and it is not possible to use anything else because there is no IT structure in Cuba to speak of. In which case of course, the complete collapse of the IT structure would be a non-event.

@JustinThymetheSecond China, did this for a while dictating what exact operating system, browser, etc. every computer in their country was required to use.  To my knowledge they have relaxed this policy quite a bit; though they still maintain extensive blacklists on foreign software.  My point about Communism is not that Communism always does this, but it is the only form of government than has or effectively can do it.

@Nosajimiki
Communism is an extreme form of Socialism. A non-Communist Socialist country could also do it. So too could an extremist right-wing hegemony. Despite the West's attempts to label China with the decidedly English label 'Communist', using the Western definition of the word, and using the English label to translate the actual Chinese term, China is not and never was a Communist country. The term 'Communism' does not occur anywhere in any Constitution-type document or any official Chinese document describing their system in China (since these documents are all in Chinese).

In real life, this cannot happen.
The Crowdstrike incident mentioned in the question had a vastly smaller real-world impact than what is implied by the media coverage.
You see, in the real world, large corporations, large cloud providers, and so on, what they do is they stagger the updates. Everybody does this, both on Windows and on Linux, because deleterious updates coming from upstream are a common fact of life. We are well aware that they occur with depressing regularity.
And you don't need any third party updates. Microsoft updates have been known to brick Windows computers.
So you don't update all your tens of thousands of cloud servers in one go; you definitely do not even attempt to update all your hundreds of thousands of end-user computers in one go. You release the update to maybe 5% of your computers, and wait to see if it had any unhappy consequences. Then you release it to 5% more. And then 5% more. Overall, it may take half a month or so until the update is fully deployed on all the infrastructure.
The point is that in reality a relatively small number of computers were affected in each of the Crowdstrike customer organizations; the IT support departments were quickly inundated with support requests, and the updates were immediately discontinued. You then put out emergency notifications to let the users and customers know what's happening and how to proceed.
Long story short, large-scale IT departments have well-established safe updating procedures, and the vast majority of organizations operating large computer networks adhere to those procedures.

In my original question, it made clear that I am not asking about 'real life', I am talking about a very constructed society.

Actually, the software update process did not allow stagged updates. That was part of the problem. But yes, it was magnified by the media coverage. It may have been lengthy, but it was easy to fix.
